# Get Response after Posting to server

Tags: android, post, get, response

To post data to the server, I use the following method, successfully posts to the server, here I need to get one number that is registration id. I have coded that in the server php. I tried with Postman works fine, but here I'm not getting. So please let me know what I have to do?

```
static String result=null;    
    private static void post(String endpoint, Map<String, String> params)
            throws IOException {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(endpoint);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url: " + endpoint);
        }
        StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
        // constructs the POST body using the parameters
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
            bodyBuilder.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
                    .append(param.getValue());
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                bodyBuilder.append('&');
            }
        }
        String body = bodyBuilder.toString();
        Log.v("TWA CLIENT REPORT", "Posting '" + body + "' to " + url);
        byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            // post the request
            OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
            out.write(bytes);
            out.close();       

            // handle the response
            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (status != 200) {
              throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
            }
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this snippets, i will work to you,

```
URL url;
url = new URL("http://www.url.com/app.php");
URLConnection connection;
connection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httppost = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
httppost.setDoInput(true);
httppost.setDoOutput(true);
httppost.setRequestMethod("POST");
httppost.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Tranz-Version-t1.914");
httppost.setRequestProperty("Accept_Language", "en-US");
httppost.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(httppost.getOutputStream());
dos.write(b); // bytes[] b of post data

String reply;
InputStream in = httppost.getInputStream();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
try {
    int chr;
    while ((chr = in.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) chr);
    }
    reply = sb.toString();
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am able to get registration Id from server