# Android HttpPost gets NULL from PHP script instead of JSONArray

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, http-post

I have a datebase with two columns (id, name) that is located at localhost:88. I'm trying to get into it from my android application, but while parsing Json the application gives JSONException. I've tryed getting the data from php without Json parsing, just a String. But it gets only NULL. 
Here is my php script:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '', 'test');

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM example");
$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    $rows[] = $r;

print(json_encode($rows));
    mysqli_close($con);     
?>
```

And here's my method:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView txt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        txt.setText(getDataFromDB());
    }

    public String getDataFromDB()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:88/basicphp/GetData.php");

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

            return response.trim();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return "error\n" + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

When i type in my browser "`http://localhost:88/basicphp/GetData.php`", i get this: "[{"id":"1","name":"John"}]". So i want to at least get this string on my TextView, but the TextView gets only null:( So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible of [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception). Consider using `AsyncTask` or `Handler`.

Comment: try this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884620/get-response-after-posting-to-server/25884706#25884706

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:88/basicphp/GetData.php");
```

it to

```
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/basicphp/GetData.php");
```

Visit [question]: [java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:8080 an android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301560/java-net-connectexception-127-0-0-18080-an-android-emulator)